# Finding the position of search hits from Lucene

Tags: java, search, lucene

With Lucene, what would be the recommended approach for locating matches in search results?

More specifically, suppose index documents have a field "fullText" which stores the plain-text content of some document. Furthermore, assume that for one of these documents the content is "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". Next a search is performed for "fox dog". Obviously, the document would be a hit.

In this scenario, can Lucene be used to provide something like the matching regions for found document? So for this scenario I would like to produce something like:

```
[{match: "fox", startIndex: 10, length: 3},
 {match: "dog", startIndex: 34, length: 3}]
```

I suspect that it could be implemented by what's provided in the org.apache.lucene.search.highlight package. I'm not sure about the overall approach though...

Answer (score 11):

TermFreqVector is what I used.  Here is a working demo, that prints both the term positions, and the starting and ending term indexes:

```
public class Search {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        Search s = new Search();  
        s.doSearch(args[0], args[1]);  
    }  

    Search() {
    }  

    public void doSearch(String db, String querystr) throws IOException, ParseException {
        // 1. Specify the analyzer for tokenizing text.  
        //    The same analyzer should be used as was used for indexing  
        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT);  

        Directory index = FSDirectory.open(new File(db));  

        // 2. query  
        Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "contents", analyzer).parse(querystr);  

        // 3. search  
        int hitsPerPage = 10;  
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(index, true);  
        IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(index, true);  
        searcher.setDefaultFieldSortScoring(true, false);  
        TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);  
        searcher.search(q, collector);  
        ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;  

        // 4. display term positions, and term indexes   
        System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");  
        for(int i=0;i<hits.length;++i) {  

            int docId = hits[i].doc;  
            TermFreqVector tfvector = reader.getTermFreqVector(docId, "contents");  
            TermPositionVector tpvector = (TermPositionVector)tfvector;  
            // this part works only if there is one term in the query string,  
            // otherwise you will have to iterate this section over the query terms.  
            int termidx = tfvector.indexOf(querystr);  
            int[] termposx = tpvector.getTermPositions(termidx);  
            TermVectorOffsetInfo[] tvoffsetinfo = tpvector.getOffsets(termidx);  

            for (int j=0;j<termposx.length;j++) {  
                System.out.println("termpos : "+termposx[j]);  
            }  
            for (int j=0;j<tvoffsetinfo.length;j++) {  
                int offsetStart = tvoffsetinfo[j].getStartOffset();  
                int offsetEnd = tvoffsetinfo[j].getEndOffset();  
                System.out.println("offsets : "+offsetStart+" "+offsetEnd);  
            }  

            // print some info about where the hit was found...  
            Document d = searcher.doc(docId);  
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("path"));  
        }  

        // searcher can only be closed when there  
        // is no need to access the documents any more.   
        searcher.close();  
    }      
}
```

Comment: The comment "this part only works if there is one term in thr query string". My next question was: how to find what terms are matched by the query (if it's a complex query (e.g. with wildcards). This answer nicely fills that gap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896183/get-matched-terms-from-lucene-query

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution for lucene 5.2.1. It works only for single word querys, but should demonstrate the basic principles.

The basic idea is:

1. Get a `TokenStream` for each document, which matches your query.
2. Create a `QueryScorer` and initialize it with the retrieved `tokenStream`.
3. 'Loop' over each token of the stream (done by `tokenStream.incrementToken()`) and check if the token matches the search criteria (done by `queryScorer.getTokenScore()`).

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.de.GermanAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.OffsetAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.InvalidTokenOffsetsException;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.QueryScorer;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.TokenSources;

public class OffsetSearcher {

    private IndexReader reader;

    public OffsetSearcher(IndexWriter indexWriter) throws IOException { 
        reader = DirectoryReader.open(indexWriter, true); 
    }

    public OffsetData[] getTermOffsets(Query query) throws IOException, InvalidTokenOffsetsException 
    {
        List<OffsetData> result = new Vector<>();

        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, 1000);

        ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = topDocs.scoreDocs;   

        Document doc;
        TokenStream tokenStream;
        CharTermAttribute termAtt;
        OffsetAttribute offsetAtt;
        QueryScorer queryScorer;
        OffsetData offsetData;
        String txt, tokenText;
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreDocs.length; i++) 
        {
            int docId = scoreDocs[i].doc;
            doc = reader.document(docId);

            txt = doc.get(RunSearch.CONTENT);
            tokenStream = TokenSources.getTokenStream(RunSearch.CONTENT, reader.getTermVectors(docId), txt, new GermanAnalyzer(), -1);

            termAtt = (CharTermAttribute)tokenStream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
            offsetAtt = (OffsetAttribute)tokenStream.addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);

            queryScorer = new QueryScorer(query);
            queryScorer.setMaxDocCharsToAnalyze(RunSearch.MAX_DOC_CHARS);
            TokenStream newStream  = queryScorer.init(tokenStream);
            if (newStream != null) {
                tokenStream = newStream;
            }
            queryScorer.startFragment(null);

            tokenStream.reset();

            int startOffset, endOffset;
            for (boolean next = tokenStream.incrementToken(); next && (offsetAtt.startOffset() < RunSearch.MAX_DOC_CHARS); next = tokenStream.incrementToken())
            {
                startOffset = offsetAtt.startOffset();
                endOffset = offsetAtt.endOffset();

                if ((endOffset > txt.length()) || (startOffset > txt.length()))
                {
                    throw new InvalidTokenOffsetsException("Token " + termAtt.toString() + " exceeds length of provided text sized " + txt.length());
                }

                float res = queryScorer.getTokenScore();
                if (res > 0.0F && startOffset <= endOffset) {
                    tokenText = txt.substring(startOffset, endOffset);
                    offsetData = new OffsetData(tokenText, startOffset, endOffset, docId);
                    result.add(offsetData);
                }           
            }   
        }

        return result.toArray(new OffsetData[result.size()]);
    }


    public void close() throws IOException {
        reader.close();
    }


    public static class OffsetData {

        public String phrase;
        public int startOffset;
        public int endOffset;
        public int docId;

        public OffsetData(String phrase, int startOffset, int endOffset, int docId) {
            super();
            this.phrase = phrase;
            this.startOffset = startOffset;
            this.endOffset = endOffset;
            this.docId = docId;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you tell how to implement it for multi-term queries? @matthiasboesinger