# Finding position of a found query in Lucene

Tags: java, search, lucene, position

Similar question is asked here:
[Finding the position of search hits from Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311199/finding-the-position-of-search-hits-from-lucene/1311281#1311281)
My problem is, the link is 3 years old and most methods are deprecated or does not even exist for Lucene 4.4 or 4.5
At first I thought `explain()` method should include everything but it does not(or not that I can see)
Here is what I get from `explain()` method. I cannot really see anything regarding to positions:

```
0.40144306 = (MATCH) sum of:
  0.13381435 = (MATCH) weight(contents:inb344 in 52) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
    0.13381435 = score(doc=52,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      0.4472136 = queryWeight, product of:
        9.574976 = idf(docFreq=44, maxDocs=238384)
        0.046706498 = queryNorm
      0.299218 = fieldWeight in 52, product of:
        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
          1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        9.574976 = idf(docFreq=44, maxDocs=238384)
        0.03125 = fieldNorm(doc=52)
  0.2676287 = (MATCH) weight(contents:inb344^2.0 in 52) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
    0.2676287 = score(doc=52,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      0.8944272 = queryWeight, product of:
        2.0 = boost
        9.574976 = idf(docFreq=44, maxDocs=238384)
        0.046706498 = queryNorm
      0.299218 = fieldWeight in 52, product of:
        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
          1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        9.574976 = idf(docFreq=44, maxDocs=238384)
        0.03125 = fieldNorm(doc=52)
```

Is there a way to see query's existing position(probably start and end positions) for a given document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer here:

http://www.computergodzilla.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-use-lucene-highlighter.html

Basically it is using version 4.2 and it works perfectly fine!

Here is the code(just in case):

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.computergodzilla.highlighter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Highlighter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.InvalidTokenOffsetsException;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.QueryScorer;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.SimpleHTMLFormatter;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.TextFragment;
import org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.TokenSources;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

/**
 * Example of Lucene Highlighter
 * @author Mubin Shrestha
 */
public class LuceneHighlighter {

    public void highLighter() throws IOException, ParseException, InvalidTokenOffsetsException {
        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File("D:/INDEXDIRECTORY")));
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_42);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_42, "ncontent", analyzer);
        Query query = parser.parse("going");
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, reader.maxDoc());
        System.out.println(hits.totalHits);
        SimpleHTMLFormatter htmlFormatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter();
        Highlighter highlighter = new Highlighter(htmlFormatter, new QueryScorer(query));
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.maxDoc(); i++) {
            int id = hits.scoreDocs[i].doc;
            Document doc = searcher.doc(id);
            String text = doc.get("ncontent");
            TokenStream tokenStream = TokenSources.getAnyTokenStream(searcher.getIndexReader(), id, "ncontent", analyzer);
            TextFragment[] frag = highlighter.getBestTextFragments(tokenStream, text, false, 4);
            for (int j = 0; j < frag.length; j++) {
                if ((frag[j] != null) && (frag[j].getScore() > 0)) {
                    System.out.println((frag[j].toString()));
                }
            }
            //Term vector
            text = doc.get("content");
            tokenStream = TokenSources.getAnyTokenStream(searcher.getIndexReader(), hits.scoreDocs[i].doc, "content", analyzer);
            frag = highlighter.getBestTextFragments(tokenStream, text, false, 4);
            for (int j = 0; j < frag.length; j++) {
                if ((frag[j] != null) && (frag[j].getScore() > 0)) {
                    System.out.println((frag[j].toString()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At the time of my writing, Lucene current version is 8.5.1. It seems that "highlight" package dissappeared a long time ago. Any idea how to achieve the same effect in this last Lucene version?