# Lucene - proximity to start of field text?

Tags: search, lucene, lucene.net, information-retrieval

I have a search field "title", within it, I want to say "things that match nearer the start of the title should be scored higher in the search results".

e.g.

```
Title: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
Title: "the lazy dogs were under the jumping quick brown fox"
Title: "The lazy brown fox jumps over the quick dog"
Title: "The brown fox made quick jumps over the sleazy dog"
```

if I search for "quick", I want the first result to be ranked top, and the 4th result to be ranked 2nd.

Is this possible within lucene? I'm using Lucene.NET / Version_29 if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

During indexing, along with every term, you can store the position of it's first occurrence in the payload of the corresponding term. During retrieval, you can work with a modified similarity function where you could take into consideration the stored position of a term in addition to the term weights.

A related SO question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311199/finding-the-position-of-search-hits-from-lucene)