Find the position offsets of highlights instead of just strings containing the fragments
The problem is instead of fragments from highlighting I really just need the positions of the highlighted word(so their start and end offsets). My original solution(but in Java) is quite similar to the solution here, where they use the token stream to score each token: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39185606/3543214
However as the comment on that solution suggests, what I really need is to find a way to make this work for more than just single tokens. The issue I'm having now is if my query is to search for "The cow jumped" I get hits on "the" "cow" and "jumped" even when they arent together. Any ideas?


If your issue is that you have hits that you actually do not want to have, then fix your query. Looks like you need to use here the PhraseQuery This way you will get only exact match.

why you guys (I checked also the post you referenced) trying to solve your issue with lucene, when you just need to write some simple pure java function to take raw search string as input and find the hits on it??? Something simple like this would work and no need to dig in to the lucene world:



public HighlightDetails getHighlightDetails(String rawQuery, String hitTerm){
 HighlightDetails result = new HighlightDetails();
 int startIndex = rawQuery.indexOf(hitTerm);
 result.Match = hitTerm;
 result.StartIndex = startIndex;
 result.EndIndex = startIndex + hitTerm.length;

 return result;
}


